# Java Sample to modify AD user "Change Password At Next Logon"

Tags: java, active-directory

Can any of you let me know how to add/edit a active directory user to enable to option "Change password at next logon"  using Java code.

I am using DirContext and ModificationItems classes to add the user to AD.

Thanks

Ramesh

Answer (score 4):

Here is the way I found to create a user through java code by enabling Change password at next logon

By setting value 0 to the "pwdLastSet" attribute, we will be able to achieve this

Comment: Minor note (too small to edit the answer). The value should be presented as a String or the update will be rejected.
``new BasicAttribute("pwdLastSet", "0")``